# Do not understand errors in basic c++ program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int number, guess;

    srand(time(NULL));
    number = rand() % 101;

    cout << "Guess a number between 0-100: ";
    cin >> guess;

    if(number > guess) {
        cout << "The number is greater!\n";
    }
    else if(number < guess) {
        cout << "The number is smaller!\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Cognratulations! The number is "number"!\n";
    }
    cin-get();

    return 0;
}
```

```
error: 'srand' was not declared in this scope
error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope
error :expected ';' before 'number'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

to include `srand()` and `rand()`

When you need to use functions like this, looking at the man pages (or googling them) will tell you which header(s) you need  to include.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer,

```
cout << "Cognratulations! The number is "number"!\n";
```

That doesn't work. You appear to be trying to construct a string out of "Cognratulations! The number is ", number, and "!\n", which is possible (but not with that syntax), but easier would be to first print the first string, then the number, and finally the second string.

```
cout << "Cognratulations! The number is " << number << "!\n";
```

Comment: That's true, but it's a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @TamásSzelei Huh? No, there are three error messages from the compiler in the question. Another answer already explained the first two, I'm explaining the third.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a discussion board. You are right, I skimmed over the third error message, so I removed the downvote. But answers should be self-contained.

Comment: @TamásSzelei I think I see your point, I didn't think it would be worth explaining the first two messages since someone else already had, but I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: The statement cin-get() wasn't even picked up by the compiler so for: it wants to read cin.get() although I would actually rather use cin.ignore() because it states better what is attempted.